# CSS navigation tab gets displayed behind the text instead of in the foreground

Tags: css, html

I have the following css code:

```
#menu li { 
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 10em; 
} 
#menu li ul {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:0em;
  margin-left:.0em;
  display:none; 
}
#menu ul li ul {
  margin-top:0em;
  margin-left:0em;
} 
#menu a {
  display:block;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  background:#3B3B3B;
  color:#3B3B3B;
  text-decoration:none; 
  padding:0 0px;
  text-align:center;
  background: url(images/nav.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu a:hover {
  background-color::#3B3B3B3;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul {
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
} 
#menu ul a {
  border-right:none;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
  background:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  background: url(images/nav.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
  height: 50px;
} 
/* SHOW SUBMENU 1 */ 
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul { 
  display:block; 
  background:#fff;
}
#menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li.over ul ul { 
  display:none;
}
/* SHOW SUBMENU 2 */ 
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.over ul {
  display:block; 
}
```

and the following HTML code

```
<div class="shell">
  <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")">HOME</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Client/SearchClient")">CLIENT LIST</a></li>
```

The problem I am having is that when the I hover my mouse over the drop down tabs - "CLIENT LIST" - It gets displayed behind the images and text that are on my page. How do I bring it to front?

Comment: add fiddle for this case

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your menu is coming under images and text, which are placed on your page. and you want to display this menu over all the content of the page.

If so, then provide a higher `z-index` value to your menu from all the content.

like: `.menutab { z-index : 1000;}` where .menutab is a class which is on your menu element.

**Edited :** make change in this line

```
/* SHOW SUBMENU 1 */ #menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul 
{ display:block; background:#fff;}
```

to

```
/* SHOW SUBMENU 1 */ #menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul 
{ display:block; background:#fff; z-index:1000;   }
```

It will solve your problem.

check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjaj4/)

Comment: Yes that is correct... I am just confused as to which line in the CSS file that the "client list" tab is referring to so i can insert it there

Comment: can you include your full html rendered code in your question? so we can check that.

Comment: thanks for helping :) ...

    <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="shell">
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
       <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Client/SearchClient")">CLIENT LIST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Client/SearchIndex")">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
       <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Booking/Index") ">BOOKINGS

Comment: </a></li>
       <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Report/Index")">REPORTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MANAGER TASKS</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SEND OUT EMAIL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">POST TEAM WALL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SET STUFF</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
             <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Login/Index")">LOGOUT</a></li>

      </ul>
   <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
  

 <!-- End Navigation -->
     </div>
    @RenderBody()

Comment: Im using mvc3 aswell so could it be possible that in the view it is getting conflicted there?

and i tried the z-index - not working

Sorry for the comments - A new user cant post answers after 7 hours or something

Comment: Appreciate this but nope - still not. I even tried to set the z-index of the image that is infront of it to: 1 but got no change